# Hypothesis Testing as a Markov Process

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, markov-process, mathematical-statistics

Consider the following multiple hypothesis testing problem. We have a finite family of distributions $\mathfrak{P}$ indexed by a set $\mathcal{V}$, that is $\mathfrak{P} = \{P_v, v \in \mathcal{V}\}$. 
Let $V$ denote the random variable representing the choice of a distribution from $\mathfrak{P}$. Then given samples $X$ from the unknown
distribution $P_V$ our task is to try to find $V$, i.e. to find out
which distribution from $\mathfrak{P}$ is generating the samples.
Let $\Psi(X)=\hat{V}$ denote our testing function. Then in page 148 of [these](https://stanford.edu/class/stats311/Lectures/full_notes.pdf) lecture notes it is stated that $V \to X \to \hat{V}$ is a Markov process.

**Question**

For $V \to X \to \hat{V}$ to be a Markov process we need 
\begin{equation}
\Pr[\hat{V} = u | X=x, V=v] = \Pr[\hat{V} =u | X=x]
\end{equation}
to hold. This is true since our estimate $\hat{V}$ is a function
of the sample $X$ and not $V$ right? Is there a more formal argument
to prove it?

**My attempt**

Since every estimator $\hat{V}$ is a function of $X$, using Bayes rule we have
\begin{equation}
\Pr[\Psi(X) = w | V=v, X=x] = \frac{\Pr[\Psi(X) =w , X=x, V=v]}{\Pr[X=x, V=v]}= 
\begin{cases} 
1 \quad \text{if } x\in \Psi^{-1}(w) \\
0 \quad \text{else }
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Similarly
\begin{equation}
\Pr[\Psi(X) = w | X=x] = \frac{\Pr[\Psi(X) =w , X=x]}{\Pr[X=x]}= 
\begin{cases} 
1 \quad \text{if } x\in \Psi^{-1}(w) \\
0 \quad \text{else }
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Therefore the two probabilities are always equal. In fact this has little to do with the testing setting I described in the question, a generic inference problem can be thought as a Markov process $X \to Y \to f(Y)$.
Is this correct?

Comment: What is the matter with "our estimate $\hat{V}$ is a function of the sample $X$ and not $V$"? What is not sufficiently formal about that?  I think if you want to be *more* formal, then you will have to rise to a level of formality that exceeds your description of the setting: specifically, you will need to introduce the entire stochastic process and use properties of conditional probability.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm fine with the simple explanation, just wanted to make sure that this a correct argument.